# In what format does your practice send patient records to individuals who request it in electronic format?

Tags: medical-records, data, healthcare-data

I am currently a student studying at The Massachusetts Institute of Technology looking to develop a new medium for patients to manage their health records. My biggest question for you all is in what format does your practice send electronic medical records to individuals who request it electronically? Are these records in PDF format perhaps?

Thank you all!

Comment: I use a company called LuxSci (Lux Scientiae, Inc.) for my solo practice. As a patient I've seen big health care organizations use Epic Systems', _MyChart_; and CernerHealth (Cerner Corporation), which has an open source platform for developers https://code.cerner.com/ . EMR delivered to patients in PDF for the most part; occasionally text files. That's simply my personal experience as a patient.